# Concatenate Specific Cell Data with Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, concatenation

I want to have a MsgBox pop up with a list of names that have missing info (either phone number or address). So far I have:

```
Dim missing As String
Do While Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""
    If StrComp(Cells(i, 1), "Need address") = 0 Then missing = Cells(i - 2, 1)
Loop
MsgBox missing
```

The spreadsheet is formatted to have all client info in Column A
in the order of:

Name

Phone Number

Address

So far, I just a 1004 Runtime Error

Comment: Whats is the value of `i`?

Answer (score 1):

You must **initialize** and  **increment** *i*

```
Sub dural()
    Dim missing As String, i As Long
    i = 1

    Do While Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""
        If StrComp(Cells(i, 1), "Need address") = 0 Then missing = Cells(i - 2, 1)
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    MsgBox missing
End Sub
```

without initializing *i*, it starts at **0** and that is the source of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Where is 'i' starting? because (i - 2) can be -2 which is not a row # in excel.